# vs2019 c# webservice msaccess

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

in vs2019 (c#) I am using very simple code

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=D:\\Data\\000_TEST.accdb";
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

and working fine: I mean - when running this code "000_TEST.accdb" this file generate "000_TEST.laccdb", and after 60-80 second it deleted automatically; I can repeat this a lot of time and everything is ok.

but when I try to use this code in webservice and calling method, it working again correctly, also generate "000_TEST.laccdb" file, and after 60-80 second deleted, but there is 1 problem:
before "000_TEST.laccdb" file is visible, calling this method is possible, and I can call this method a lot of time, 
but after 60-80 second - when "000_TEST.laccdb" file deleted and not visible, when I am trying call this method, I am getting error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
   at WSTest.WebService1.Incr(String conStr, Int32 a) in D:\My Documents\VS Projects\WSTest\WSTest\WebService1.asmx.cs:line 41
```

Note: line 41 is -  "conn.Open();"

Comment: That's your "Access lock file". I don't have a fix for you, but I would like to suggest that maybe you try with sqllite or Sql Express rather than Access. I don't believe Access is viable for a webservice as it can be a fickle beast with concurrent users...plus the licence :)
Oh, maybe try a `conn.Dispose()` after your .Close...see if that will clear it up...otherwise you should show more code around the db usage.

Comment: thank you for answer, but: 
1. Access is viable for webservice, it working fine but limited time, when this lock file is present, after that I getting this error.
2. conn.dispose() did not solve problem.
3. Use sq db is better, but this project is old and there are a lot of data (tables) avaialbe already in access db, so because requirement only for web service update, before it was only 1 user on 1 PC, now they ned in local net and later on internet,

Comment: I'll agree to disagree on your Access/Webservice viability. But, if you want help you will need to show more code around your data access. Good luck.